react-dropzone does not load document in mobile browser
Recently, I finished a project where I used react-dropzone. Uploading files works fine on desktop browsers, but on mobile browsers, the files don't load.
Btw, it's only accepted PDF files
That is the code of the component:
const UploadDropzone = ({ isSubscribed }: { isSubscribed: boolean }) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState<number>(0);

    const { toast } = useToast();

    const { startUpload } = useUploadThing(
        isSubscribed ? "proPlanUploader" : "freePlanUploader"
    );

    const { mutate: startPolling } = trpc.getFile.useMutation({
        onSuccess: (file) => {
            router.push(`/dashboard/${file.id}`);
        },
        retry: true,
        retryDelay: 500,
    });

    const startSimulatedProgress = () => {
        setUploadProgress(0);

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setUploadProgress((prev) => {
                if (prev >= 95) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return prev;
                }
                return prev + 5;
            });
        }, 1000);

        return interval;
    };

    return (
        <Dropzone
            multiple={false}
            accept={{ "application/pdf": [".pdf"] }}
            onDrop={async (acceptedFiles) => {
                setIsUploading(true);

                const progressInterval = startSimulatedProgress();

                // Handle the file uploading
                const res = await startUpload(acceptedFiles);
                if (!res) {
                    return toast({
                        title: "Tamanho de documento excedido",
                        description: "Por favor, tente com um documento menor!",
                        variant: "destructive",
                    });
                }

                const [fileResponse] = res;

                const key = fileResponse?.key;

                if (!key) {
                    return toast({
                        title: "Algo deu errado",
                        description: "Por favor tente de novo!!!",
                        variant: "destructive",
                    });
                }

                clearInterval(progressInterval);
                setUploadProgress(100);
                console.log("File uploaded");
                startPolling({ key });
            }}
        >
            {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, acceptedFiles }) => (
                <div
                    {...getRootProps()}
                    className="border h-64 m-4 border-dashed rounded-lg border-zinc-400"
                >
                    <div className="flex items-center h-full w-full justify-center">
                        <label
                            className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-zinc-50 hover:bg-zinc-100"
                            htmlFor="dropzone-file"
                        >
                            <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
                                <UploadCloud className="mb-2 h-6 w-6 text-zinc-600" />
                                <p className="mb-2 text-sm text-zinc-700">
                                    <span className="font-semibold">Clique </span>
                                    ou arrasta e solta
                                </p>
                                <p className="text-sm text-zinc-600">
                                    PDF até {isSubscribed ? "16MB" : "2MB"}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            {acceptedFiles && acceptedFiles[0] ? (
                                <div className="max-w-xs bg-white flex items-center rounded-md overflow-hidden outline outline-[1px] outline-zinc-200 divide-x divide-zinc-200">
                                    <div className="px-3 py-2 h-full grid place-items-center">
                                        <File className="h-4 w-4 text-blue-500" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="px-3 py-2 h-full text-sm truncate">
                                        {acceptedFiles[0].name}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ) : null}
                            {isUploading ? (
                                <div className="w-full mt-4 max-w-xs mx-auto">
                                    <Progress
                                        indicatorColor={
                                            uploadProgress === 100 ? "bg-green-600" : ""
                                        }
                                        value={uploadProgress}
                                        className="h-1 w-full bg-zinc-200"
                                    />
                                    {uploadProgress === 100 ? (
                                        <div className="flex gap-1 items-center justify-center text-sm text-zinc-700 text-center pt-2">
                                            <Loader2 className="h-3 w-3 animate-spin" />
                                            Redirecionando...
                                        </div>
                                    ) : null}
                                </div>
                            ) : null}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        {...getInputProps()}
                        type="file"
                        id="dropzone-file"
                        className="hidden"
                    />
                </div>
            )}
        </Dropzone>
    );
};

I'm trying to create a upload button that i can load files, from desktop and mobile browser.
